# jsp:param don't display the expected value

Tags: java, spring, jsp

In my spring project, I have two layers for my views:

1) each method from my controller map directly a jsp page like that:

```
<jsp:include page="../../common/listagem.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="name" value="Usuario"/>
    <jsp:param name="elements" value="{['login','senha','pnome','unome','email']}"/>
</jsp:include>
```

2) my jsp page common/listagem.jsp is this:

```
<%@ include file="../include/header.jsp" %>

<sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'cadastra_${param.name}')">
<p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link link" data-action="/${param.name}/cadastra">
        Cadastrar novo ${param.name}
    </button>
</p>
</sec:authorize>

<table class="bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${param.elements}">
            <th> <c:out value="${item}"/> </th>
        </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="content">
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'altera_${param.name}')">
                <td class="comando" data-nome="Altera" data-action="/${param.name}/altera"></td>
            </sec:authorize>
            <sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#user, 'remove_${param.name}')">
                <td class="comando" data-nome="Remove" data-action="/${param.name}/remove"></td>
            </sec:authorize>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<c:url value="/${param.name}/listagem.json" var="listagem"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_content("${listagem}", $('table.bordered'));
});
</script>

<%@ include file="../include/footer.jsp" %>
```

My problem it's exactly with the page above. the final result for this code is that:

[image]

but instead should display only the title of the columns in the top and the code:

```
<c:url value="/${param.name}/listagem.json" var="listagem"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_content("${listagem}", $('table.bordered'));
});
</script>
```

should fill the table with data from the server (this code works in other project mine, where I don't use include files and jsp:param).

Anyone can see what's wrong with this code?

Comment: what are you expecting? It's string and displaying as it is.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `$`?

Comment: @Braj what form I should use?

Comment: I can help you but at least can tell me what are you expecting?

Comment: I need display only the names, without the `{}` `[]` or `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solve this issue using an array for store the values, like that:

```
<jsp:param name="elements" value="login"/>
<jsp:param name="elements" value="pnome"/>
<jsp:param name="elements" value="unome"/>
<jsp:param name="elements" value="email"/>
```

and in the common jsp page:

```
                    <c:forEach var="item" items="${paramValues.elements}" varStatus="status">
                        <th class="col" data-property="<c:out value="${item}"/>">
                            <c:out value="${paramValues.label[status.index]}"/>
                        </th>
                    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [JSP JSTL Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html) but it more like a JSON string so try with [Jackson JSON Parser](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Find tutorial on Jackson parser [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

Sample code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>

<c:set var="elements" value="${param.elements}" />
<c:forEach var="item"
    items="${fn:split(fn:substring(elements,2,fn:length(elements)-2),',')}">
    <c:out value="${item}" />
</c:forEach>
```

output:

```
'login' 'senha' 'pnome' 'unome' 'email'
```